# How do I install a file to an existing directory in Android

Tags: android, xml, file, copy, patch

I want to create a simple app for android. I want it to install an .xml file to another apps existing directory when the user runs the app and clicks the install button. It is a patch for an existing app. I have created the .xml file but I want to make it easy for users to patch their app. Seeing as my Android knowledge is limited, I was wondering if I could get some help with this. I'm sure it's simple. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Who wrote the original app? If it was you then just update the app and users can download the new version. If you didn't write the other app then you stand no chance unless the other app is running on devices with older versions of Android and the XML is to be copied on to the SD card. The latest versions of Android restrict access to the "storage" however and that's not going to work. Either way it seems like you're asking us to write code for you and that's not what we do here - Stack Overflow is for helping people to fix problems in code they've already written.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible, at least without rooting the device and running your app as root.
This is so by necessity - think what would happen if any application could modify other apps files.